# Movement of electrons in a circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current

Electrons move from negative to a positive terminal, but their path seems unusual.

They seem to be taking the longer path to get to the positive terminal, The electrons could have gotten closer to the positive terminal from inside the battery rather going out of the battery, I know this wouldn't work because there is a barrier obstructing their path, But electrons wouldn't 'know' this, so why do they take a longer path to reach their destination even though that's the only way?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Electrons take the only possible path to the other terminal.

Comment: Imagine a battery, electrons do not know that their is some barrier obstructing their path (the battery case, separates positive and negative charges) electrons would go towards what their attracted, but to actually reach the inside the part of the battery where the positive charges are present they would have to use up more energy, how did they know that if they spend a little more energy they will get that sweet positive charge, the only thing they do is go towards the path that attracts them more, but they go the other way.

Comment: Are you certain that the electrons would be attracted in the way that you say? Remember, what determines the force on electrons is not the presence of other charges, but rather the presence of the _electric field_. So the question you should ask is: where does the electric field point?

Comment: How does water "know" to get from say, Arapahoe Pass in Colorado, all the way to the Gulf of Cali?

Comment: If the electrons can move from negative to positive inside the battery, we call that an internal short circuit and it drains the battery quickly.

Answer (score 4):

A battery is effectively an electron pump. Inside a typical battery there is a chemical reaction called a [redox reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox) occurring. This reaction consumes electrons at the positive end and produces electrons at the negative end, so the net result is that it pumps electrons from the positive terminal through the battery to the negative terminal. The electrons pumped out of the battery at the negative terminal then flow through the external circuit and finally back into the positive terminal, ready to being their journey once more.